# How to separate a component's controller function into a different file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been searching and searching, and maybe I have been using the wrong terms on my search, but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for. I am using Angular 1.5 with components.

Say I have a component A:

```
var module = angular.module('myApp');

module.component('A', {
  templateUrl: 'template.html',
  controller: function(){}
});
```

Now this is very simple. I also know that I can do the following, as long as 'myControllerFunction' is in the same file.

```
var module = angular.module('myApp');

module.component('A', {
  templateUrl: 'template.html',
  controller: myControllerFunction
});

function myControllerFunction(){}
```

Now what do I do if I want to have a file only for 'myControllerFunction'? How do I access that function inside that file from within my component?

I know that using Node.js is easy to use exports and require(), but I am not quite familiar what to do using AngularJS.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by moving it to another file?

Comment: charlietfl, I'm just trying to better organize my code. The example I provided is quite simple, however the actual code I'm working is quite longer. So I'm trying not to pollute that specific file by creating my component controllers elsewhere.

Comment: the norm is one component per file and if your controller code is really long something is wrong and you aren't using services properly

Comment: You're probably right. It's a school project I have going on and the deadline is coming soon, but I'll try to separate more things using services as much as I can when I have more time. Thanks, charlietfl!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can refer the controller from your module like below :

```
module.component('A', {
  templateUrl: 'template.html',
  controller: 'YourController'
});
```

Then in the another file you can define controller with the method.

```
function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').controller('YourController',
            YourController);

    YourController.$inject = [ '$scope', '$http', '$window',
            '$rootScope' ];

    function YourController($scope, $http, $window, $rootScope) {       
        function yourcontrollerfunction() {
        }
        yourcontrollerfunction();               
    }
})();
```

yourcontrollerfunction function will automatically called when controller is loaded. Controller will be loaded when your module is loaded.

Comment: Ah, cool! So you can just create a controller on that module and the component's controller attribute will find it. I'm going to test it quite soon and then mark the answer as solved if it worked out as it probably should. Thank you!